# how to exec long time task only use BroadcastReceiver in android?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I 'm writing a backgroud app only can use service. 
I'use BroadcastReceiver start service.  Sometimes it works well, but some sometimes it doesn't work.

I know the reason is  BroadcastReceiver exec liftcycle is 10 seconds, so use it start a long time task will not be end.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(context, RegisterService.class);
context.startService(i);
```

What should I do if I want to execute a long time task only use BroadcastReceiver and service?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your service is not executing on the main thread. Consider using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), it does the right thing out of the box.